# Problems in virtual work

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

How virtual work is applied in this question?

[image]

Comment: The "Method of virtual work" sounds like a very specific method. It must be defined specifically in this book - or googlable.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like its asking for the compressive force acting on the horizontal beam B-D. Here's how you use "virtual work" to solve the problem:

Imagine that the horizontal beam B-D of length $l$ increases in length by some small amount $\epsilon$. From the diagram you can see that such a small increase in length will cause the 20 kN weight at point C to slightly rise up. That takes work because the gravitation potential energy of the weight will have slightly increased. So, by inspection and using a little algebra and trigonometry, you should be able to calculate how much work is done if the length of the horizontal beam B-D were to increase in length by a small amount $\epsilon$. In fact, in the limit of a very small increase in the beam length of $\epsilon$, the amount of work done should be just linearly proportional to $\epsilon$.

But the amount of work done when the horizontal beam increases by a small amount $\epsilon$ is also equal to the compression force on that horizontal beam multiplied by $\epsilon$, that is, it's equal to $F\epsilon$, where $F$ is the compression force that you want to determine.

So all you need to do is to calculate the infinitesimal or "virtual" work that is done if the horizontal beam were to increase in length by a small amount, and by recognizing the fact that that work has to be equal to $F\epsilon$ you should then be easily able to calculate the force of compression on the horizontal beam.

Comment: Sir  can u show the diagram of how u have considered   and my another question what is thrust on bd and its direction

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what they mean by virtual work.

---

Pull the string down by dx. Work done is 20dx.  Since change in K.E. is zero, this work should be equal to the work done to compress the rod. Using geometry find the change in length of middle rod when you pull the string down by dx. Thrust force * that Change in length = 20dx.
Hope it helps.

---

And all the best ;)

Comment: Can u suggest what is thrust force in beam bd and its directikn

Comment: It is the compressive force on the rod.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual work replaces the required force, in this case the compressive force in the horizontal bar with a virtual force, and then you take the moments about a point that does not include the virtual force, so since the frame is symmetrical, take split the frame, in half and take moments about the pinned joint. You can quickly determine the forces in the lower member, resolved into its two components, since it is an equal angle triangle, with angle of 60 Degrees.